python generic type hint list
I have a python function:
def func (l:list):
    pass

It can be used with any array-like objects: list, np.ndarray etc 
How should I annotate l?
I saw that some modules use typing.Iterable class as annotation. But this protocol does not contain neither __len__, nor __getitem__ methods, which are necessary for my l parameter
Update: 
Thanks to people from commentaries, now know that I need typing.Sequence, since it has both len and getitem methods.
But unfortunately it does not help: I cannot use ndarray. It says "ndarray[Any, dtype[float64]]" is incompatible with "Sequence[Unknown]"
Is it even possible to write a function with a generic argument, which can accept both list and ndarray?

This table might help.

Sequence possibly

This question is similar to: Type hints for Sized Iterable in Python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@InSync, thank you, this helps a lot. Still, it does not answer all of my needs. I modified the question.

See also Python type hint for classes that support __getitem__. A Protocol with both __len__ and __getitem__ is what you need.

Can you add a small example of the numpy code are trying to use.

If you want to have a function that accepts both Sequences and NDArray, just use a union to express both:
import numpy as np
from typing import Sequence
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def func(l: Sequence | NDArray):
    pass

a1 = np.array([2,3,5])
a2 = [1,2,3]

func(a1)
func(a2)

And the good news is, if it turns out you also know the type of argument in each of these objects you can specify that too. See below for assuming float:
import numpy as np
from typing import Sequence
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def func(l: Sequence[float] | NDArray[np.float_]):
    pass

a1 = np.array([2,3,5])
a2: list[float] = [1,2,3]

func(a1)
func(a2)

Hope this helps!
